# seatgeek api pulling events out of hash in array in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

i'm having trouble pulling events from the seat geek api.

I can pull a title when giving an id for instance https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events/3475509

```
"links": [],
"in_hand": {},
"id": 3475509,
"stats": {
"listing_count": 401,
"average_price": 133,
"lowest_price_good_deals": 71,
"lowest_price": 71,
"highest_price": 932
},
"title": "Toronto Raptors at Chicago Bulls"
```

i can pull the title out like so: require 'Unirest'

```
    @events = []
    @events << Unirest.get("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events/3475509?&client_id=////").body
    @events.each do |event|
     puts event["title"]
    end
```

which returns the title of the event I get that but when I make a call to the seatgeek api and try to return mutliple events in a given area I'm having trouble for instance:https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?datetime_utc.gt=2017-01-07&datetime_utc.lte=2017-01-30&geoip=104.18.37.48&range=20mi&client_id=NjQwNTEzMXwxNDgxNDkxODI1
which retunrs this displays every event in san fran betweens these dates what I would like to do is pull out each event from this. here is what I have so far 
require 'Unirest'

```
@events = Unirest.get("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?datetime_utc.gt=2017-01-07&datetime_utc.lte=2017-01-08&geoip=104.18.37.48&range=20mi&client_id=NjQwNTEzMXwxNDgxNDkxODI1").body
@c = @events["events"]
@c[0..9].each do |event|
 p event["title"]
```

end
its only returning 2 titles rather then 10 not sure why I'm not getting an error anymore at least any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: question is not very clear. try to rewrite pls. the use of proper punctuation may increase the readability.

Comment: sorry its first post on here i was able to get it to work correctly though I will try to be more clear in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It should print all the titles.

```
@events = Unirest.get("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?datetime_utc.gt=2017-01-07&datetime_utc.lte=2017-01-08&geoip=104.18.37.48&range=20mi&client_id=NjQwNTEzMXwxNDgxNDkxODI1").body
@events["events"].each do |event|
  p event["title"]
end
```

Comment: thanks that works mine worked as well I had the dates off,  if I were to do @c[0..9].each do |event| it would give me the first ten elements of event correct?

Comment: yes, it should give.
Also, If the answer solves your problem, you should mark it as `answer`